# Any gotchas with using one CloudFront distribution as a custom origin in another distribution?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

We serve a lot of our org's content through one big CloudFront distribution.  It has cache behaviors that route traffic to various components in our system.  We manage the distribution with CloudFormation.  As we manage more and more components (some with Lambda@Edge) this one distribution is getting a bit complex.

I'd like to start breaking up this distribution into smaller pieces to limit that complexity and to limit blast radius.  To this end, I'm thinking about putting some behavior into a new distribution that serves as a custom origin of our main distribution.

I see very little about this approach on the web, which worries me :-) Anyone know of any documentation or blogs about this?  Are there any gotchas here that others have experienced?  E.g. is there significant extra latency?  I can imagine that this might incur extra HTTPS request charges (as each request would in effect be hitting two distributions instead of one).